# Oracle restore to a differnet drive

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have the following script for rman to backup the main database and archive logs:

```
connect target sysdba/password@localhost/db
run
{
allocate channel d1 type disk;
crosscheck archivelog all;
delete noprompt expired archivelog all;
crosscheck backup;
delete noprompt expired backup;
backup AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET tag Full_database_open format 'E:\backup\data\db_%Y_%M_%D_%t_%s_p%p.dbf' database;
sql 'alter system archive log current';
sql 'alter system archive log current';
backup AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET archivelog all format 'E:\backup\data\al_%Y_%M_%D_%t_%s_p%p.dbf' delete all input;
delete noprompt obsolete redundancy = 1;
backup AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET current controlfile tag =cf1 format 'E:\backup\data\cf_%Y_%M_%D_%t_%s_p%p.dbf';
crosscheck archivelog all;
delete noprompt expired archivelog all;
crosscheck backup;
delete noprompt expired backup;
}
```

The data files are in: `E:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\DB\`

I am trying to setup a test server, but installed oracle in the C:\ drive.
How, so the data file is: `C:\app\administrator\oradata\DB`

I tried the following:

```
-- sqlplus 
shutdown abort;
startup nomount;

-- rman
restore controlfile from "C:\backup\data\CF_2019_08_27_1017362393_20_P1.DBF";

-- sqlplus
alter database mount;

-- rman
restore database;
```

unfortunately the backup tries to write data to the `E:\` drive which is not present in the test server.

How can I make oracle restore the files to: `C:\app\administrator\oradata\DB` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
run
{
  set newname for database to 'C:\app\administrator\oradata\DB\%U';
  restore database;
}
switch database to copy;
```

This will generate filenames in the specified directory. If you want nice looking names following your naming convention, specify them manually, example:

```
run
{
  set newname for datafile 1 to 'C:\app\administrator\oradata\DB\system01.dbf';
  set newname for datafile 2 to 'C:\app\administrator\oradata\DB\sysaux01.dbf';  
  ..
  restore database;
}
switch database to copy;
```

[SET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta2014.htm)

Comment: Thanks: Here are  my steps. 1. shut abort; 2. startup nomount; 3. restore control file ... 4. rman connect target ...  5. alter database mount; 6. set name script. Errror: 
creating datafile file number=1 name=C:\app\administrator\oradata\DB\data_D-MSH_
TS-SYSTEM_FNO-1
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 12/10/2019 10:36:31
ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'E:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORADATA\MSH\SYSTEM01.DBF'

Comment: Hmm.. interesting `list backup of datafile 1;` seemed to want the backup file to be in the same path where it was saved. :( ... I moved the file to a similar path and i could restore it.